# Is it possible to downgrade Unity3D v.5.5 to e.g. 5.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, downgrade, unity3d

I can't sign into Unity3D v.5.5 (downloaded [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/)) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It constantly says that the service isn't available. I tried re-installing Unity3D v.5.5, but it didn't help.

I went through recommendations from a couple of threads (can't enumerate all of them as don't have enough reputation). I even deleted Chrome as some folks mentioned that it might interfere. Currently the option that is left is to install Unity3D v.5.4 or v.5.3.

Thus, the question is whether it's possible to successfully downgrade Unity3D?